# Two sets of reals with $n$ elements in common

Tags: calculus, puzzle

> Given a positive integer $n$, find real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that the sets $X=\{x,2x,3x,\ldots\}$ and $Y=\{y,y^2,y^3,\ldots\}$ have exactly $n$ elements in common.

I haven't been able to get anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:
$$x = \frac 1 {2^n}, \quad y = \frac 1 2$$
Then:
$$X = \left \{ \frac 1 {2^n \strut}, \frac 1 {2^{n-1}}, \dotsc, \frac 1 {2 \strut}, 1 \right \} \cup X'$$
where $X'$ is a set of fractions having numerators different than $1$, and
$$Y = \left \{ \frac 1 {2 \strut}, \frac 1 {2^2}, \dotsc, \frac 1 {2^n \strut}, \frac 1 {2^{n+1}}, \dotsc \right \}$$
Therefore $X$ and $Y$ have exactly $n$ elements in common.